# Disable powersuit text (or move it)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm using my PowerSuit, and doing some Thaumcraft things at the same time, but the UI elements for both overlap. Is it possible to disable or move the powersuit text?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually edit the Thaumcraft config to display the wand UI in the bottom left instead of the top.  It looks like this, under the "general" heading:

> # Set to true to have the wand dial display in the bottom left instead of the top left.
>       B:wand_dial_bottom=false

I couldn't find any UI settings in the Modular Powersuits configs :/